# INNER JOIN Identifiers Change on Joining or Replacing Data while Inserting to a Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I am getting data from a linked server, in which lets say I am having an identifier which I am joining with the identifier on my server and getting the data for it.

But the thing is identifier from Linked server contains some extra characters and while joining its not able to correctly join.

Can i do something like this that when I join, I will replace the identifies extra characters with space or `NULL`.

For ex.

```
Table 1
Col1     Col2
23rf     name
24rf     id

Table 2
Col1     Col2
23       name1
24       id1

SELECT
      ta1.*,
      ta2.* 
FROM Table1 ta1
INNER JOIN  Table2 ta2
ON ta1.Col1 = ta2.Col2
```

So this will give `NULL`

I want a query which can result the data by replacing "rf" to "" and join the two table, so that I can't get a `NULL` DataSet.

Second Approach:
Can I insert the data from one table to another table where while inserting, I can replace "rf" to "".
But, I do not know how to proceed for the above approach.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you must be using sql server since you mention a linked server but you have tagged both mysql and sql server. Which one is it? They are not the same thing. Assuming it is sql server have you looked at the REPLACE function? You pretty much have the exact syntax in your question.

Comment: you can add functions to the expression in the join. It may work slow, but it will work: `INNER JOIN  Table2 ta2 ON REPLACE(ta1.Col1, 'rf', '') = ta2.Col2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning an id to each of your tables using `ROW_NUMBER`. So, I used now row as their common field. See and try my queries below:

In **SQL-SERVER**:

```
SELECT ta1.Col1,ta1.Col2,ta2.Col1,ta2.Col2 FROM
(SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS Row,* 
FROM Table1) AS ta1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS Row,* 
FROM Table2) AS ta2
ON ta1.Row=ta2.Row
```

In **MYSQL**:

```
SELECT ta1.Col1,ta1.Col2,ta2.Col1,ta2.Col2 FROM
(SELECT
     @row_number1:=@row_number1+1 AS RowNumber1,
     Col1,
     Col2
FROM Table1, (SELECT @row_number1:=0)AS x ORDER BY Col1) AS ta1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
     @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS RowNumber2,
     Col1,
     Col2
FROM Table2, (SELECT @row_number2:=0)AS y ORDER BY Col1) AS ta2
ON ta1.RowNumber1=ta2.RowNumber2
```